# getnameinfo() can it be used to return multiple hostnames for a single IP address

Tags: c, sockets, dns, network-programming, hostname

I have an ip address 5.5.5.5 and there are two hostnames pointing to it.

From the command line

> host  5.5.5.5

DNS.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer address1.test.com.

DNS.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer address2.test.com.

> nslookup  5.5.5.5

Server:     dns.test.com

Address:    dns.test.com

Non-authoritative answer:

DNS.in-addr.arpa    name = address1.test.com.

DNS.in-addr.arpa    name = address2.test.com.

I am trying to implent this type functionality in c/c++. When I use getnameinfo() it only returns address1.test.com or address2.test.com.

My question is there away to get both of these DNS names in one call? 
how does nslookup and host do this?

Code :

```
    char host[1024];
    std::string inputAddress = "5.5.5.5";
    struct sockaddr_in socketAddress;
    socketAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, inputAddress.c_str(), &(socketAddress.sin_addr));
    getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&socketAddress, sizeof(socketAddress), host, 1024, NULL, NULL, 0);
    printf("host=%s \n", host);
```

Comment: can you provide your code by editing your question?

Comment: There is no `std::string` in C language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The `getnameinfo()` interface can only return a single name — it has no way of returning multiple results. Its behavior is undefined when multiple PTR records are returned; in practice, most implementations will probably use the first one they see.

Keep in mind that [there should only be one PTR record (and, thus, one canonical hostname) for any given IP](https://serverfault.com/a/618775/15323). While it is possible for more than one A/AAAA name to resolve to a single IP, only one of those names should ever appear in a PTR record.

Comment: Yes this is the answer the issue is the IP address had 2 PTRs in it and it should not. Thanks a lot duskwuff